# Using CSS3 Animations in IE9+

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-9, css-animations

I have been trying to get these css3 animations to work in IE9 for a few hours today and I am stumped!

I tried implementing a few JavaScript fallbacks but my knowledge is very limited so they failed. I am unsure if it was failing due to my user errors or code errors.

Here is a jsFiddle of my code so far, I have replaced the background images with colours. Basically the green and black squares rotate in Firefox and Webkit browsers.

http://jsfiddle.net/fJxsV/

I want to have it running on IE9 also.

If you can please help me with this I would be very grateful!

Comment: CSS3 transitions and animations don't work in IE9. They *should* work in IE10.

Comment: They do work in IE9 with jQuery libraries allowing them to. I just don't know how to implement this. http://addyosmani.com/blog/css3transitions-jquery/

Comment: Not quite :). That plugin tests for transition support, and if support is detected, uses pure CSS transitions. Otherwise it uses jQuery's internal animation functions to perform the animation. The plugin doesn't enable CSS3 transitions in IE9, and jQuery doesn't natively support rotation animations. You need to use a plugin like this: http://www.zachstronaut.com/posts/2009/08/07/jquery-animate-css-rotate-scale.html, but this won't do the fallback type stuff as per your link. So if it *MUST* work in IE9, don't worry about the native CSS3 stuff, just do all the animation in JS using this plugin.

Comment: Mmm, I tried the link that you posted. I couldn't seem to get it to work though. Would you be able to assist me with the implementation of this?

Comment: IE10 coming soon to Windows 7 so there is chance for more working features in this popular system.

Answer (score 24):

I would use [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) to detect when css animations are not supported. With Modernizr, it's as simple as:

```
if(!Modernizr.cssanimations) {
    //jQuery fallback 
}
```

As for rotating with jQuery I would use: http://jqueryrotate.com/

Comment: It is not the answer. The question is how!

Comment: The question has already been answered in the comments above (CSS3 transitions and animations don't work in IE9). My answer is a solution to the fact that you can't use CSS3 animations in IE9.

Comment: Thank you very much for mention jQuery rotate.