# CSS3 animation not working in IE9

Tags: internet-explorer, css, css-transforms, css-animations

CSS3 animations are not working in IE9. Here is the [jfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/8Pcv4/). Is it possible to make them working on IE or i am making some silly mistake? Here is the code which is not working:

```
@-ms-keyframes rotating {
  0% { -ms-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -ms-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

#rotateMe{
  -ms-animation: rotating 5s linear infinite;
}
```

As IE doent support this functionality i have created the fallback using [jquery rotate plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/)

here is my fallback function for IE:

```
$(function() {
    if (!$.support.transition){
        var angle = 0;
        var angle2 = 0;
        setInterval(function(){
              angle+=0.3;
              angle2-=0.3;
             $(".rotateRing").rotate(angle);
             $(".rotateRingReverse").rotate(angle2);
        },50);
    }
});
```

Comment: **$.support.transition** is not a native and is not part of jQuery. this is created by twitter bootstrap to detect the availability of CSS3 transitions.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

CSS3 Animation don't work natively on IE9. There's a similar thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060223/using-css3-animations-in-ie9)

Comment: Tnx for your reply. Btw, I have just created the fallback for IE using this plugin http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/