# Insert css animation internet explorer javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I want to insert a animation with javascript in internet explorer. Seems not to work. With chrome, ff no problem. Please check out these link:

```
var style = document.documentElement.appendChild(document.createElement("style")),

rule="@keyframes test{ 0%{opacity:1;} 50%{opacity:0;} 100%{opacity:1;}} ";
style.sheet.insertRule(rule);

$(".mojo")[0].style["animation"] = " test 3s ease-out both infinite";
```

http://jsfiddle.net/273e2/17/

Is animations are working with IE10. Inserting the animation in runtime it seems not to work.

Comment: what version of internet explorer are you using? animations should be working from internet explorer 10 only.

Comment: In which IE are you testing ? IE8 and less doesn't support full CSS3.

Comment: @Vucko Not even IE9 and 10. Specifically, IE9 doesn't support animations either...

Comment: you might also be interested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11923368/css3-animation-not-working-in-ie9 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060223/using-css3-animations-in-ie9

Comment: @MaxArt I know, but the OP didn't mention in which IE is testing. IE9 compare to IE8 is a starship. You can the css3 suport with [css3 test](http://css3test.com/).

Comment: I've tested it in IE10. Doesn't work in any version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`insertRule`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff975163%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method expects two values; the first being the new rule string, and the second being the index at which you would like it to be added among other rules.

An index of `0` will push the rule to the top, and an index equal to the number of rules total will push it to the bottom of the rules.

```
// Add a new rule to the bottom of the first stylesheet
sheet.insertRule( rule, sheet.rules.length );
```

Adding this index to your demo fixes the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/273e2/19/show/

Comment: @Abc [It made all the difference](http://jsfiddle.net/273e2/19/show/); I opened your demo in IE10 and it didn't work. I added an index, and that fixed it.

Comment: ok i will try it tomorrow. I was thinking I've already tried it.

Comment: @Abc Were you able to confirm this solution?