# Not displaying div in internet explorer 9 possible opacity issue

Tags: html, css

I think from my current reading up on documentation and google related searches that IE 9 doesn't like opacity... I have this css and wanted to know why IE 9 doesn't like it... can anyone add to my understanding on this?

```
#logo-title{
  background-image: url("../images/mthc/logo-whole.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 250px;
  border: 0 ;
  height: 180px;
  width:780px;
  z-index : 2500;
  opacity:0;
```

EDIT :- Further reading concludes that the below code is actually the problem as ie9 doesn't support all the good stuff in css3 .... a js alternative needs to happen but unable to get this code to work...

```
$("#logo-title").fadeIn();


-webkit-animation: fadein 2s; /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
           -moz-animation: fadein 2s; /* Firefox < 16 */
            -ms-animation: fadein 2s; /* Internet Explorer */
             -o-animation: fadein 2s; /* Opera < 12.1 */
                animation: fadein 2s;
        -webkit-animation-delay: 11s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        animation-delay: 11s;
        -moz-animation-delay: 11s;
        -ms-animation-delay: 11s;
        -o-animation-delay: 11s;
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
        -o-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
        -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
        -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards; 
    }
```

EDIT - I FORGOT TO INCLUDE THE FADEIN ANIMATION ...

```
@-ms-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}
```

Comment: I believe there are issues with IE9 and css3 animations http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11923368/css3-animation-not-working-in-ie9

Comment: Actually IE9 Supports opacity.  But could you please elaborate on how it's doesn't like opacity ???

Comment: ah yes basically the bacground url isn't viewble but is clickable , i agre with the other comment perhaps it is the webkit animation lack of support that isn't making it visible in a different related script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that CSS3 Animations aren't supported in IE9 and you need to use a fallback, such as [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) - as mentioned in this thread:  [Using CSS3 Animations in IE9+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060223/using-css3-animations-in-ie9)

Comment: That is what seems really odd , I am currently using modernizr 2.6.2 ??

Comment: could it be that the @keyframes aren't supported?  Can you do a fallback, such as creating a class with desired properties and then use javascript to addClass on pageload?

Comment: well i was thinking as it is a simple opacity changes using a fadeTo but not sure what do you think ?