# how to make it spin in IE 9

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, glyphicons

`glyphicon-refresh-animate` is working in Chrome, Firefox and IE 10 but not in IE 9. it is not spinning.

I tried to add this in CSS but it's not working

```
.glyphicon-refresh-animate {
    animation: spin .7s infinite linear;
    -ms-animation: spin .7s infinite linear;
}
```

Anybody knows whats wrong?

Comment: ie 9 doesnt support animation http://caniuse.com/#search=animation

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20693190/i-need-css3-transition-to-work-in-ie9

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11923368/css3-animation-not-working-in-ie9

Comment: aw.. THANK you.. I already found that link.. but maybe someone make it works or they have other alternative to make it spin in IE 9 ^_^