# IE10 hover effect not working

Tags: css, hover, sass, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-10

I have a hover effect on a button, when you hover the button another div container with a width:0 expands to width: 150px;

```
//hidden element
.twitter-options-wrapper {
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: -58px;
  right: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: width 250ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: width 250ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: width 250ms ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: width 250ms ease-in-out;
  transition: width 250ms ease-in-out;
}
```

then, the hover *I'm using Sass in case you wondering about the nesting

```
.btn-twitter-options:hover {
  .twitter-options-wrapper {
    width: 150px;
  }
}
```

This work on everything except IE9 - 10 which makes no sense since I have another button with a hover effect and works fine, the only difference is this button expands its width from 30 - 40px on hover.

Any ideas or hacks for IE 9 or 10.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a Sample Demo please so we can get a clear picture.

Comment: here you go http://codepen.io/anon/pen/cHmDi

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you want `css transitions` in IE9? According to: [I need CSS3 transition to work in IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20693190/i-need-css3-transition-to-work-in-ie9)
IE9 doesn't understand `transitions`... :( There is also a hack how to animate it using JS.

IE10 wise - I've just tested it on http://www.browserstack.com/ and animation did work.

Answer (score 0):

so I found the answer, and css transitions do work on IE 9  and above. The issue was related to having the options-wrapper inside a container with a position absolute. so the animation was occurring inside the actual button, the solution was as simple as adding overflow: visible; to the the actual button (.btn-twitter-options) this solve the issue entirely. I had a similar issue like that before on IE9 where a button with a point arrow made by css using the before pseudo element wasn't displaying on IE. The solutions was the same, apply overflow:visible to the button and the :before element would display as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Issues related to `overflow: hidden` should be solved by the addition of:

```
-ms-overflow-style: auto;
```