# How to write the CSS3 code to run the Animation in IE9 browser

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9

I tried the animations using CSS3.But the animations are not working in the IE9 browser.Is there any possibilities to run the animations in IE9 browser?

Comment: More info would be helpful what you're trying to achieve but I believe you're looking for something like in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20693411/574397

Comment: I wrote the CSS3 code using CSS cssSandPaper plugin to do the animation.
I include the cssSandpaper.js 
code:
      -sand-transform:matrix(2,0,0,2,0,0);
Is there any way to execute the transform in IE9?