# jQuery msAnimationEnd doesn't work on Ie9

Tags: jquery, callback, internet-explorer-9

Hi all I have big problem with IE9. msAnimationEnd doesn't work in other browsers it work fine but in ie9 not

```
http://bozenart.es/gallery/
```

in this link you can test it

Can some one help me how fix that please

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation ie9 does not support it.

Comment: it's not good, can we find some other solution to detect it maybe with transition

Comment: Internet Explorer 9 did not support animations. Show us what you're doing, and perhaps we can help you identify a work-around for Internet Explorer 9.

Comment: Perhaps [this previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20693411/54680) could be helpful.

Comment: http://bozenart.es/gallery/ you can see it on this page click on image and in normal browser you can see animation. i using jquery animationend callback to start or end some animations